# A least sized partition of a set under a distance metric

Tags: np-hardness, computational-geometry

What is the worst case complexity of an algorithm to find a least partition of a set under a distance metric, described as follows:

**Input**:

- A set $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$, where the elements $s_i$ are of some type $T$.
- A distance metric $D:T\rightarrow [0, \infty)$.
- A radius $r:[0, \infty)$

**Output**: A partition $S_1,\ldots,S_m$ of $S$ such that

- $S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset, i\neq j$ and
- $S=\cup_{i=1}^m S_i$ and
- $D(s,t) \leq r$, $s,t \in S_i$ and
- There is no other partition with the same properties of size $m^{\prime} < m$.

**NOTE:** I am saying "a partition" not "the partition", because there may be multiple partitions of least size for the same set of points.  For example consider $2 n$ points on a large circle where the points are spaced such that each pair of points is distance $r$ apart.  In this case there are $2 n-1$ distinct least-sized partitions of minimum size $n$.

**NOTE:** The following algorithm will produce a partition with desired properties except that it is not guaranteed to be least size:

- $i=1$
- While $|S| > 0$:

  - Choose $e \in S$ and set $S:=S-\{e\}$
  - $S_i=\{x\in S: D(e,x) \leq r\}$
  - Set $S:=S \setminus S_i$
  - Set $i:=i+1$

**NOTE:** It has been suggested that this is an NP-hard problem, but the above partial solution is $O(n^2)$.

**NOTE:** This problem is an abstraction of [this geographic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075481/how-do-i-cluster-a-list-of-geographic-points-by-distance).

Answer (score 4):

Ken Supowit proved that the following problem is NP-hard: Given a set $P$ of $n$ points in the Euclidean plane and an integer $k$, partition $P$ into $k$ clusters so that the largest cluster diameter is minimized.

> Kenneth J Supowit: "Topics in Computational Geometry"
>   Ph.D. thesis, Dept. of Computer Science, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign (1981), Report UIUCDCS-R-81-1062

Tomás Feder and Dan Greene proved that even the problem of approximating the smallest possible cluster diameter within a factor of $1.97$ is NP-hard.

> T Feder, D.H Greene: "Optimal algorithms for approximate clustering"
>   Proceedings of the 20th Annual ACM Symposium on the Theory Computing (1988), pp. 434-444

Comment: Can you translate my problem into either of these problems?  They don't seem to be the same problem.

Comment: Also the distance function is not necessarily Euclidean, it is an arbitrary real-valued metric.  For example Vincenty distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae